# Referral program - keep query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a way to maintain a query string entry in all routes. I am adding the option of a referral program in the application.

Let's say the main URL is:

```
www.example.com
```

We also have :

```
www.example.com/faq 
www.example.com/about 
www.example.com/login
```

I want to share my code and I could share it in any path, let's say I share the following url:

```
www.example.com/faq?refCode=123
```

If the person I sent the url to decides to check the about page, the result should be the following (keeping the referral code):

```
www.example.com/about?refCode=123
```

I have been able to handle this value in the controller but I need to keep the parameter in the URL.

I hope it is understood and thank you very much!

Comment: You mean exactly what existing tools like google analytics are built to do? I think you're understimating the complexity involved in reinventing the wheel here. If you for example monkeyed with `default_url_options` to make Rails tack your tracking query string on every link on your site you just made your entire site very hard to cache. Then there are pesky things like GDPR...

Comment: I mean if you really wanted to do this from scratch I would just ask the user to consent to a cookie and store the referral code in a cookie. If you really want to tack it onto all the links you can then use JS to add it to add the links. This will let you use fragment caches without worrying about user specific data getting in the way as well as e-tag caches.

Comment: @max is a requirement of the client and he showed us other sites that do it, I don't know what can be done with google analytics. That's why I'm looking here for some guidance and to know if it could be done natively in rails. I'll see what I can do with JavaScript, thanks!